# base64 image uploaded as 0 byte and file_put_contents returning false in php

Tags: php, base64, image-uploading, file-put-contents

I am trying to upload multiple base64 images in for loop using file_put_contents() function but ***sometimes*** files are uploading as a ***0 bytes*** image and file_put_contents() function returning false. How to solve this? Help is appreciated.

```
$filename = 'appimages/'.date('Y-m-d').'/'.$user_id.'/'.$clientCode;
                if (!file_exists($filename)) {
                    mkdir($filename, 0777, true);
                }

$id = $db->lastInsertId();
                $error = 0;
                $ef = 0;
                foreach ($images as $img) {
                    if(!empty($img)){
                        $image = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $img->imgs));
                        // $image = base64_decode($img->imgs);
                        $image_path = $filename.'/'.mt_rand( 100000 , 999999 ).'.png';
                        if(file_put_contents($image_path, $image)){
                            $main_image_path = 'https://consult-trico.com/bank/api/'.$image_path; 

                            $stmt11 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO daily_transaction_images(dt_ID, deposit_slip_no, image, created_at) VALUES(:dt_ID,:deposit_slip_no,:image,:created_at)");

                            $stmt11->execute(['dt_ID' => $id,'deposit_slip_no' => $img->name, 'image' => $main_image_path, 'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
                        }else{
                           $error++; 
                       }
                   }
                   ++$ef;
               }
```

Comment: What is `$images`, where does that come from? Have you checked what it contains in a case where such an error occurs? Have you verified whether replacing the `data:image…` prefix worked as intended?

Comment: Where does this code upload anything? I see no usage of `$_FILES` or anything similar